# Probability of finding a green signal on two consecutive days.

Tags: probability

The probability of finding a green signal on a busy crossing X is 3/10.
 What is the probability of finding a green signal on two consecutive days out of three??

**It's very urgent. Please answer quickly!**

Comment: Is the urgency because of an exam? By the way, does is imply **exactly two** consecutive days? Or is three out of three days also acceptable?

Comment: Yes. It's urgent due to exam.

Comment: So are we helping you to cheat in an exam?

Comment: @MattiP. I don’t think phones are allowed during exams.

Comment: I had given the exam( CBSE 12 )and am at my home now. I want to know the answer.

Comment: I don't get probability much. So I can't tell you whether it means exactly two. The question was asked as you can see in the post . I have only replicated it.

Comment: It's really urgent for me! Please quick your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let G be the event of a green signal.

Required probability $=P(GGG’)+P(G’GG)$

$= \left({\frac {3}{10}} \right)^2 \cdot \frac{7}{10} + \frac {7}{10} \cdot \left({\frac{3}{10}} \right)^2$

$= \frac {126}{1000}$

Comment: A very very thanks to you.